# Is there an official map of Querencia?

Tags: map, commonwealth-saga

There are official maps for [Bienvenido](https://www.facebook.com/PeterFHamilton/photos/for-ivka-l%C3%B6rincov%C3%A1-who-wanted-a-map-of-bienvenido/780539378698319/?paipv=0&eav=AfbSLb4Gyo8l_qZns5fveze3oSPVrcZnDdvYprcBt02R2P8zf_j4u0tt8WQ32qUQdXc&_rdr#_=_) which appears later on in the series and for the city of [Makkathran](https://web.archive.org/web/20160717031810/http://www.peterfhamilton.co.uk/uploads/images/Makkrathan_small.jpg). The map for Bienvenido  is featured in the physical books yet I have been unable to find one for the planet of Querencia - partly because it shares a name with real life locations.

Comment: They don't have one in-universe - "*‘Doesn’t it even bother you that we don’t actually have a complete map of Querencia? The ships that brought Rah and the Lady must have seen what it looked like before they landed. Why didn’t any survive?’*"

Comment: @Valorum that would make a good answer then :)